# empty nsarray crashes uitableview

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

I am catching a bunch of data from my server then parsing it, I then pass this parsed data over to a method that sorts my array alphabetically.. all of this is working but my tableview is displaying before I have any data in the array so my app is falling over... how can I stop this from happening?

```
//...
tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:
//..
//configure cell
[[cell textLabel] setText:[sortedArray objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]]]; // this is where I am passing the data into each cell
///

//parsing stuff happens here then I passed the parsed data over to my sorting method...


//method to sort array and split for use with uitableview Index
- (IBAction)startSortingTheArray:(NSMutableArray *)arrayData
{
    //Sort incoming array alphabetically
    sortedArray = [arrayData sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)];

    //Reloads data in table
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

error msg

```
2011-09-16 15:04:06.096 Code[8630:207] -[UILabel objectAtIndex:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x4c767e0
2011-09-16 15:04:06.099 Code[8630:207] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UILabel objectAtIndex:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x4c767e0'
*** Call stack at first throw:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x010da5a9 __exceptionPreprocess + 185
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0122e313 objc_exception_throw + 44
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x010dc0bb -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 187
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x0104b966 ___forwarding___ + 966
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x0104b522 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 50
    5   Code                           0x0003d225 -[VehicleResultViewController tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:] + 405
    6   UIKit                               0x0063bb98 -[UITableView(UITableViewInternal) _createPreparedCellForGlobalRow:withIndexPath:] + 634
    7   UIKit                               0x006314cc -[UITableView(UITableViewInternal) _createPreparedCellForGlobalRow:] + 75
    8   UIKit                               0x006468cc -[UITableView(_UITableViewPrivate) _updateVisibleCellsNow:] + 1561
    9   UIKit                               0x0063e90c -[UITableView layoutSubviews] + 242
    10  QuartzCore                          0x01ee0a5a -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 181
    11  QuartzCore                          0x01ee2ddc CALayerLayoutIfNeeded + 220
    12  QuartzCore                          0x01e880b4 _ZN2CA7Context18commit_transactionEPNS_11TransactionE + 310
    13  QuartzCore                          0x01e89294 _ZN2CA11Transaction6commitEv + 292
    14  QuartzCore                          0x01e8946d _ZN2CA11Transaction17observer_callbackEP19__CFRunLoopObservermPv + 99
    15  CoreFoundation                      0x010bb89b __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 27
    16  CoreFoundation                      0x010506e7 __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 295
    17  CoreFoundation                      0x010191d7 __CFRunLoopRun + 1575
    18  CoreFoundation                      0x01018840 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 208
    19  CoreFoundation                      0x01018761 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 97
    20  GraphicsServices                    0x018971c4 GSEventRunModal + 217
    21  GraphicsServices                    0x01897289 GSEventRun + 115
    22  UIKit                               0x005d4c93 UIApplicationMain + 1160
    23  Code                           0x00002609 main + 121
    24  Code                           0x00002585 start + 53
)
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'NSException'
```

UPDATED// initializing array to 0 inside viewdidload is now giving me a "EXC_BAD_ACCESS" error

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.sortedArray = [NSArray alloc];
}
```

Comment: Is there a good reason why you cannot display the table after you get your datasource the way you want it to?

Comment: Your mistake is `sortedArray =...`, which is not a setter call. See my answer below.

Comment: In your new edit, you mean `self.sortedArray = [[NSArray alloc] init];` -- you must call the initializer. In any case, why instantiate the sorted array at all? At least you managed to call `self` this time! :)

Comment: Im not sure I understand your question, you are saying "you must call the initializer" then  your saying "why instantiate the sorted array at all?"...

I think this is the answer y ou might be looking for " I have more processes to put my data through, I have to break them up into alphabatised sections so that I can use the index searching function of the uitableview..

Comment: In general if you allocate, you must init too. However I'm saying you can do away with allocating/instantiating your `sortedArray` altogether. When the time comes, you're going to assign it to a sorted array you've generated and retain then instead. Also remember, when you allocate you give an object a retain count +1. If you allocate you're responsible for releasing once, so you would have to make an extra release call some where.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like `sortedArray` is `nil` or has a retain count of zero, and that's confusing the debugger as to its class. I've seen this in my own code when I've allowed this to happen: Your problem stems from using `=` with no `self` in sight and as such you're probably creating a zombie. If in doubt, run the Analyzer in 'Product -> Analyze' (XCode 4.*).

To fix the problem, you need to use the synthesized getters and setters. In your interface, I recommend declaring some thing like:

`@property(retain) NSArray * sortedArray;`

and some where in your implementation:

`@synthesize sortedArray;`

Then, instead of `sortedArray = [arrayData sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)];`, which is bad because it bypasses all retention, do:

`[self setSortedArray:[arrayData sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)]];` or

`self.sortedArray = [arrayData sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)];`

They're equivalent. Although an `=` appears in the second option, the compiler will recognize this as a setter call, correctly managing the retain count.

Last, in the `dealloc` method of your subclass you must release `sortedArray` before calling `dealloc` on `super` otherwise you'll have a memory leak.

In general I would do away with `ivar`s as much as possible, except for managing some kind of internal state for your custom object that should be private. If by default you call say `[self myMember]` or `[self setMyMember:]` you will discipline yourself and save yourself the stress of making this mistake.

If you're feeling particularly confident, personally I'd override the setter for your array with some thing like:

```
- (void) setSortedArray:(NSArray *) anArray
{
  // Make this thread safe by surrounding with a lock.
  @synchronized(self)
  {
    // Always retain the new before releasing the old, in
    // case the old and new are the same object!
    [anArray retain]
    [self.sortedArray release];

    // Set the data array; we don't call on self here.
    sortedArray = anArray;

    // UIKit is not thread safe so we push the reload
    // call onto the main thread; blocks only work in
    // iOS4.1 and up, otherwise perform selector in
    // the background:
    // [self.tableView performSelectorInBackground:@selector(reloadData) withObject:nil];

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
      // Update the table
      [self.tableView reloadData];
    }];
  }
}
```

Also declare the property with

`@property(nonatomic, assign, setter = setSortedArray:) NSArray * sortedArray;`

You need `nonatomic` here as the compiler can not promise your custom setter will be thread safe. (Instead we're ensuring it's threadsafe.) In any case you'd still be able to compile, but the compiler would warn you about this.

NB. I haven't tested the above code, I wrote it out in SO's box.

Comment: This worked perfectly! and I have understood what your saying... more attnetion to detail is whatI need atm.. than you very much for you help and contribution to the reast of the answers.

Comment: You tell me - I took it from your question. See 'arrayData' in your question. (In your question I suspect you really meant 'dataArray' perhaps.)

Comment: yea I had a moment.. I was thinking about your solution being for something else but then I realised you were talking about what was going on down in my startSortingTheArray method where arrayData is the data coming in from my parserDidEndDocument delegate method... Thank you very much for you help! :)

Comment: Since you're downloading some thing from a server you might end up doing this in the background, if not now then later. Beware that UIKit is not thread safe - if you call a UI object from a secondary thread you'll either crash or the UI won't appear to respond. To over come this, you move UI calls on to the main thread. Even if you don't need this right now, I suggest overriding the setter and moving UI calls (such as reloading data) to the main thread by default - then you can forget about this.

Answer (score 0):

Regardless of whether it is a UITableViewController or a UITableView inside another view controller, first set the data source the way you want it to be and then proceed. If it is a UITableViewController, my suggestion would be to override the init method and pass the sorted array to it as an extra argument. Otherwise if it is a UITableView within another view controller, sort the array and only then create the UITableView object and add it as a subview.

EDIT:
And as xuzhe says below, is your sorted array even an array object in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

Your error log shows that you're sending the objectAtIndex message to a UILabel.  This is causing the crash.  At least this line isn't calling objectAtIndex on the cell label:

```
[[cell textLabel] setText:[sortedArray objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]]];
```

Is there anywhere else if your code that you're calling objectAtIndex?  Hit Ctrl + F and search for 'objectAtIndex' in your view controller.m

Answer (score 0):

Also, note the error message says that a UILabel doesn't recognize the msg objectAtIndex:

I'm guessing that sortedArray is uninitialized, and just happens to be a leftover UILabel. (Especially as you show it getting set later).

If you're intending sortedArray to hang around, make it a property, and always refer to it as self.sortedArray (so it will get initialized, and properly retained/released).

Comment: That's not it. His array is a zombie - he's missed off calling the setter in `-startSortingTheArray:`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass 0 in

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section 
{

}
```

before you have some data in the data source array. One solution is,

-> Initialize the sortedArray (with no objects in it) before you load the table view perhaps in viewDidLoad

```
self.sortedArray = [NSMutableArray array];
```

->   And return the array's count in numberOfRows

```
 - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section 
    {
      return [self.sortedArray count];
    }
```

->Reload the table after you finish adding the data to the array

```
//Make sure you call this when there is some data in the sorted array
[self.tableView reloadData];
```

Comment: This didnt work, But I understand what your saying.. It giving a new error now about UITapRecognizer, I will add the out put to my question.

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.sortedArray = [NSArray alloc];
}
```

To this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.sortedArray = [NSArray array];
}
```

Comment: I just tried this, and got a new error **erminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UILongPressGestureRecognizer objectAtIndex:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x4c78490**

Answer (score -1):

```
- (IBAction)startSortingTheArray:(NSMutableArray *)arrayData
{
    //Sort incoming array alphabetically
    sortedArray = [arrayData sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)];

    //Reloads data in table
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
[arrayData sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)];
```

**returns auto released  array. so cannt use further .so take ownership from that array by retain or copy or alloc.then ur problem will sloved**